# How to add a line to a file within a specific section by using a bash script?

Tags: bash

I'm writing a bash script which will eventually automate user configuration for Apache.
I have this part of the apache configuration (`httpd.conf`):

```
NameVirtualHost X.X.X.X:80
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName qa-market.local
  DocumentRoot /var/www/networks
  Alias /alex /var/www/networks/net-32
  Alias /daniel /var/www/networks/net-24
</VirtualHost>
```

I want the script to add another `Alias` directive within the `<VirtualHost></VirtualHost>` section and after the last `Alias` line.
That's the directive I want the script to add:

```
Alias /\$user /var/www/networks/\$userdir
```

How can it be done? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
user=foo
userdir=bar
sed "/<\/VirtualHost>/i\  Alias /$user /var/www/networks/$userdir" filename
```

Comment: The $user and $userdir are variables.. I want their value inserted in the `path` directive instead of "$var" , how is it done please?

Comment: I've updated my answer.